# Does SQLite scan unused tables in a query?

Tags: sqlite

I have a query like this

```
explain query plan select t1.c from t1, t2 where t1.id = 0;
```

The return is

```
selectid order from  detail
"0"      "0"    "0" "SEARCH TABLE t1 USING PRIMARY KEY (id=?)"
"0"      "1"    "1" "SCAN TABLE t2"
```

In my case, t2 is not used in either where or select clauses. Why does SQLite still plan to scan it...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause) says:

> If the join-operator is … a comma (",") and there is no ON or USING clause, then the result of the join is simply the cartesian product of the left and right-hand datasets.

So the other table needs to be scanned to determine the number of rows to return:

```
> CREATE TABLE t1(c);
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('c');
> CREATE TABLE t2(x);
> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1), (2);
> select t1.c from t1, t2;
c
c
```